# Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174: Not capturing data packets in monitor mode

Tags: 16.04, wireless, atheros, wireshark, airmon-ng

I am using an Dell Latitude 3480 laptop which comes with the **Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174** Wifi card with Ubuntu OS (16.04 Release). When I use it as a sniffer (using `wireshark`) after enabling monitor mode using `airmon-ng`, I am only able to get Beacon and Probe response frames (which are the management packets).

**I am not able to get the data packets in wireshark**.

I tried sniffing packets from an tcp traffic run between an Netgear AP and a client in 5G network with open-none security.

**Is this an expected problem with this card?**

I tried reinstalling the driver and all, but no change. The kernel I use is 4.4.102-0404102-generic.

**Can someone really help me out?**

Answer (score 0):

Do you use custom drivers? As far as I know linux distros that are capable of sniffing wifi have custom drivers installed, like Kali, Backbox and so on.
I don't think there is a problem with the card itself, but rather with the software.

I suggest you try using Kali or other distros and use tools like airodump-ng, so you can rule this out.